# Find all anchor elements that are inside h3 elements

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this code to find all a tag elements that are inside h3 tag (have h3 parent) but unfortunatelly it returns an empty list.

```
r = requests.get('some_url_here')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
a=soup.find_all('h3>a')
```

How I can get all these a tag elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `soup.select('h3 > a')`

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h3><a href="">link1</a></h3>
<h3><a href="">link2</a></h3>
<h3><a href="">link3</a></h3>
<h3><a href="">link4</a></h3>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

a = soup.select('h3 > a')

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[<a href="">link1</a>, <a href="">link2</a>, <a href="">link3</a>, <a href="">link4</a>]
```